# Google Sheets - If value in cell X is between minimum value in column A and maximum value in column B then return related value in column C

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S_elApF2NAA7gTpWXjkf9w_IbE4tLvnefRL7XaS64Ac/edit?usp=sharing)

I have two columns defining the minimum (A) and maximum (B) (of correct answers). Pupils results are in column C and Grades in D.

What I am trying to do is check is a number of correct answers and then show the corresponding grade.

The formula works for E2. The formula only works for E2.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(C2:C;
 {QUERY(IFERROR(
  (A2:A); ); "SELECT Col1")\
  QUERY(A2:D; "SELECT D")}; 2)); )
```

[image]

Comment: Super! Much nicer and shorter code - that works. too Thank you :-)